# Setting QIcon() pixmap from URL

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

how can i set Qicon from a url in PYQT , can you give me an example?

Comment: Take a look at [QWebSettings.iconForUrl (QUrl url)](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebsettings.html#iconForUrl) method.

Comment: this will be fetch the website icon not icon file hosted on the site

Comment: Do you mean: receive the file *hosted at the URL* and use this as the icon? And *not* the "favicon" of the website which is typically used as the tab icon and in favorites menu in browsers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a basic example would be:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest

app = QApplication([])
url = "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico"
lbl = QLabel("loading...")
nam = QNetworkAccessManager()

def finishRequest(reply):
    img = QImage()
    img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
    lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))

nam.finished.connect(finishRequest)
nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))
lbl.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `requests.get` method to download the image and create a `QIcon` from it.

```
import sys
import requests

import PySide6
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableView, QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QHeaderView
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, QIcon, QPixmap

from datetime import datetime

class MagicIcon():
    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link
        self.icon = QIcon()
        try:
            response = requests.get(self.link)
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            pixmap.loadFromData(response.content)
            self.icon = QIcon(pixmap)
        except:
            pass

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(MagicIcon(
            "https://img.icons8.com/external-flatarticons-blue-flatarticons/65/000000/external-analysis-digital-marketing-flatarticons-blue-flatarticons-1.png"
        ).icon)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = MainWindow()
    wid.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```