# PyQt5 5.9 , setWindowIcon( QIcon(*WEB_LINK*) )

Tags: python, pyqt, qicon

**Hi,** I have an issue with my PyQt5 setWindowIcon.

When I try to set my window icon from a local image, it works perfectly. But when I try to put a online link like:

`setWindowIcon( QIcon("https://www.google.ge/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico") )`

it does not work. What to do? Its 32x32 ico btw.

~Thanks

Comment: Are you serious? Just download it and save it to disk.

Comment: Lol, I am building a dynamic thing...

Comment: @ვანიჩკაა the url that Qt uses only refers to local files or files that are in a .qrc, if you want to use an url icon you should download it anyway, if this changes you should download it and update it again. If you want to know how to download it with PyQt read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735977/setting-qicon-pixmap-from-url

Comment: @ვანიჩკაა. That makes no difference. One way or another, the image file will have to be downloaded. How else do you imagine it could work?

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you, but I noticed that it applies to a second, and then disappears, do you have any idea whats going on here?

Comment: @ვანიჩკაა. Apply what? Apply how? I have no idea what you're trying to do now.

Comment: The icon is working for second and then disappears when using following code in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `QNetworkAccessManager` and *manually* download image from url. Then read bytes from response, create a QPixmap (beacuse it has [loadFromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-1) method) and initialize a QIcon from QPixmap.

And after that you will be able to set window icon.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout

ICON_IMAGE_URL = "https://www.google.ge/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico"


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.label = QLabel('Image loading demo')

        self.vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(self.vertical_layout)

        self.nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.set_window_icon_from_response)
        self.nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(ICON_IMAGE_URL)))

    def set_window_icon_from_response(self, http_response):
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(http_response.readAll())
        icon = QIcon(pixmap)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. i will try it later

Comment: @Pixsa it's been 3 years...

Comment: @BlueGuy Sorry, mate, I gave up on it :D

Comment: That probably is the solution